# Gutenberg: Dynamic rendering of RichText

Tags: block-editor

When I save `<RichText />`s content into my attributes and want to use this with `render_callback` in php, it get's kinda messy. As soon as the text contains RichText (bold, italic, line-breaks etc.), `$attributes` stores it really complicated

```
attributes: {
    description: {
        type: "text",
        // no source, so it goes straight into the html comment, nice for dynamic rendering
    }
}


...
"render_callback" => function( $attributes ) {
    return "<p>" . $attributes["description"] . "</p>"
}


// var_dump($attributes["description"]
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "Rendering RichText with "
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "strong"
      ["key"]=>
      string(10) "_domReact4"
      ["ref"]=>
      NULL
      ["props"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["children"]=>
        string(3) "php"
      }
      ["_ower"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [2]=>
    string(22) " is a pain in the a..."
  }
```

I guess there is a reason why they save RichText like this. 
Question now is:

How can I use it when rendering dynamically? 
Is there some function I don't know of? Like: `wp_decode_richtext()`

Answer (score 0):

The attribute in question should have the type of "string" so that it would be rendered properly.

```
attributes: {
    description: {
        type: "string",
    }
}
```